# How to solve a QCQP where constraints are balls?

Tags: oc.optimization-and-control, convex-optimization, approximation-algorithms, closed-form-expressions, qcqp

I want to solve the following optimization problem in variables $\theta_1, \theta_2, \dots, \theta_K$

\begin{equation}
    \begin{aligned}
    & \underset{\theta}{\text{minimize}}
    & & \sum_{k=1}^{K} \|g_k - \theta_k\|_2^2 \\
    & \text{subject to}
    & & \| \theta_m - \theta_l \|_2^2 \leq \| x_m - x_l \|_2^2 , \quad 1 \leq m < l \leq K,
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

where $x_i$ and $g_i$ are constants and $\| \cdot \|_2$ denotes the Euclidean norm.

Is there any closed-form for arbitrary $K$? Or an appropriate first-order iterative method which yields an approximate solution?

Comment: Thank you for your question. I've clarified it now. It's the Euclidean norm

Comment: Have you tried to rewrite in terms of the incidence matrix of the underlying graph?

Comment: I doubt there can be a closed-form solution for $K \geq 3$. I would rewrite the problem in a saddle point form and then apply some first order method. But you need to give more details: what is the dimension of $\theta_k$, how big is $K$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I haven't, but I'm more interested on the type of approach suggested by the next answer. Thank you for your idea anyway

Comment: @cheyp: K can be arbitrarily large, in fact. But let's assume that it can be as high as 128, for example

Comment: Have you tried a second order (i.e., the "usual" kind) SOCP solver, such as Mosek, Gurobi,  CPLEX, or XPRESS? Is it too big to fit in memory?

Comment: I've tried using CVX and I believe it uses one of those. However, it becomes too slow for higher K. That's why I was wondering about a first-order method @MarkL.Stone

Comment: The default for CVX is SeDuMi or SDPT3, neither of which are as good as Mosek or Gurobi, which both can be used under CVX. You re probably best off not squaring any of the norms, so as not to square condition numbers.